# Haskell - No instance for (Ord Pos) arising from a use of `minimum'

Tags: haskell

I am currently having a bit of an issue with making this bit of code work with my data type. It works fine when I use

`type Pos = (Int, Int)`

however I need to use

`data Pos = Pos (Int, Int) deriving (Show, Eq)`.

For the rest of the code I have been able to change it to `(Pos(x,y))` which has worked however for this one function it is throwing this error message.

```
* No instance for (Ord Pos) arising from a use of `minimum'
* In the second argument of `(.)', namely `minimum'
  In the expression: snd . minimum
  In the expression:
    snd . minimum $ [(score p, p) | p <- allBlanks puzzle]
```

This is my function:

```
blankX2 puzzle = 
  snd
  . minimum $ 
  [(score p, p) | p <- allBlanks puzzle] where
    score (Pos(y,x)) = rowScore y + colScore x + sqScore (div x 3, div y 3)
    rowScore r = blanksInBlock (row r puzzle)
    colScore c = blanksInBlock (column c puzzle)
    sqScore sq = blanksInBlock (square sq puzzle)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First said, albeit unrelated to your question: don't wrap tuples in `data`, better make them *fields* of the data type. In this case you also want to make the fields strict, for performance:

```
data Pos = Pos { xPosition, yPosition :: !Int }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Now, you need an `Ord` instance too. Well, the easiest way is to add that to the `deriving` list!

```
data Pos = Pos { xPosition, yPosition :: !Int }
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Alternatively, you could also define it yourself, perhaps because you want a different ordering from the standard one. To do that, you'd write

```
instance Ord Pos
```

The compiler would then complain:

```
warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        either ‘compare’ or ‘<=’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Ord Pos’
  |
3 | instance Ord Pos
  |          ^^^^^^^
```

Ok, so we'd better add one of those methods. `<=` is easier to understand, but `compare` more directly covers all cases and is therefore recommended. To see what you need to do, start with a stub:

```
instance Ord Pos where
  compare = _
```

GHC answers:

```
• Found hole: _ :: Pos -> Pos -> Ordering
• In the expression: _
  In an equation for ‘compare’: compare = _
  In the instance declaration for ‘Ord Pos’
• Relevant bindings include
    compare :: Pos -> Pos -> Ordering
      (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6330.hs:4:3)
```

So you need to implement `compare` as a function with that signature.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Pos` datatype needs to be an instance of the `Ord` type class in order to be used by `minimum`. That type class provides comparison functions, such as `<`. Just add `Ord` after `Show` and `Eq` to let GHC derive the necessary functions for you automatically.